# CKFinder2: CKFinderJava.war not working

Tags: ckfinder

Here are some screen shots of the CKFinderJava.war in action.

http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/306/standalonet.jpg

[http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/9856 ... lonev1.jpg](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/9856%20...%20lonev1.jpg)

http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/1897/popupd.jpg

Any chance if one could get that war file working properly?

Thanks.

Comment: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=22843&p=58105#p58105 might help solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[CKFinderJava.war](http://www.mediafire.com/?oik77u7pz21kp8b) (link now broken) was the working sample application of the `CKFinder 2` version with the given issue fixed. The newer `CKFinder 2.1` version could be found at [CKFinder 2.1](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=23438).